# Dynamic Data tables joining Using Linq

Tags: linq, datatable, dynamic-data

I have two data tables  whose columns are dynamic and they both have one common column.
Now I want to join these two tables.
To get combined result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "data table with dynamic columns", what exactly do you mean? Is it untyped `DataTable`, is it a list of `ExpandoObject` or `DynamicObject` derived instances, or something completely different?

Comment: Actually a stored procedures will return two tables  with ID ,Name as the common Columns in both the tables.Which will have equal number of columns but the column names are different.We need to combine both the tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you might be looking to join the two data tables which are generated on runtime. Check out this link. Might be useful for you

[Finding common columns from two datatable and using those for Join condition in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259711/finding-common-columns-from-two-datatable-and-using-those-for-join-condition-in-l)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use AsEnumerable() on the tables and to join them on the common column data.

Let's assume that your tables look like this:   `[Table1] -> [ID] [Name] [Location]   |   [Table2] -> [ID] [Description]` and the ID column has the same values

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table1.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
table1.Rows.Add(1, "Name1", "Location1");
table1.Rows.Add(2, "Name2", "Location2");
table1.Rows.Add(3, "Name3", "Location3");

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table2.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
table2.Rows.Add(1, "Description1");
table2.Rows.Add(2, "Description2");
table2.Rows.Add(3, "Description3");
```

Then you just have to join the tables on the ID columns and select the resulting data set

```
var joinedTables = from data1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                   join data2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on data1.Field("ID") equals data2.Field("ID")
                   select new {  id= data1.Field("ID"), 
                     name = data1.Field("Name"), 
                     loc = data1.Field("Location"),
                     desc = data2.Field("Description")
                   };
```

The resulting data:

```
id name  loc       desc
1  Name1 Location1 Description1
2  Name2 Location2 Description2
3  Name3 Location3 Description3
```

Comment: Acutally I need all the columns from both the tables and only one common column.In the select statement I dont want to mention specific columns in the select new {}

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy, more so without using `ExpandoObject` because LINQ is generally tuned to produce strongly typed objects for which you need to know the schema at compile time. A way I see this happening is through combining method being invoked via transformation, where the method will generate a dynamic object with a combination of all discovered fields

```
public ExpandoObject CombineMe(DataRow r1, DataRow r2) 
{
    dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
    x.ID = r1.Field<int>("ID");
    x.Name = r1.Field<string>("Name");

    // use Expando as dictionary
    IDictionary<String, Object> xd = (IDictionary<String, Object>)x;

    // enumerat both rows for all columns not ID and Name and add to Expando
    foreach (DataColumn c in r1.Table.Columns) 
        if (c.ColumnName != "ID" && c.ColumnName != "Name") 
            xd.Add(c.ColumnName, r1[c]);
    foreach (DataColumn c in r2.Table.Columns)
        if (c.ColumnName != "ID" && c.ColumnName != "Name")
            xd.Add(c.ColumnName, r2[c]);
    return x;
}

/// .... further down

var p = from a in table1.AsEnumerable()
        join b in table2.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<int>("ID") equals b.Field<int>("ID")
        select CombineMe(a, b);
```

select in linq is not exactly like SQL select, it just provides a placeholder for transformation be it simple, complex or even external calling code.

NOTE: If you do not want to use dynamic then a solution can be similarly made by first enumerating all columns in both tables and creating a third table. CombineMe is then changed to generate `DataRow` instead of `ExpandoObject` and p is finally enumerated and all its entries (combined instances of `DataRow`) are added to the resulting table.