# DataTable Join using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I am joining two data tables using LINQ this way:

```
 DataTable targetTable = dataTable1.Clone();
 var dt2Columns = dataTable2.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(dc =>
        new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType, dc.Expression, dc.ColumnMapping));
 var dt2FinalColumns = from dc in dt2Columns.AsEnumerable()
                       where targetTable.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName) == false
                       select dc;
 targetTable.Columns.AddRange(dt2FinalColumns.ToArray());

 var rowData = from row1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
               join row2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
               on row1.Field<string>("keyCol") equals row2.Field<string>("keyCol")
               select row1.ItemArray.Concat(row2.ItemArray.Where(r2 => row1.ItemArray.Contains(r2) == false)).ToArray();
 foreach (object[] values in rowData)
     targetTable.Rows.Add(values);
```

I am facing three issues here:

1. In case of row count is not same for two tables, I want to pass default value or assign empty string for values not found in other table. How do I achieve this ?
2. If I have multiple columns and need to compare with AND how is that possible ?
3. What if I have to join multiple tables in run time. Is there any way to generate dynamic LINQ ?

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to do this with LINQ instead of using DataTable.Merge()?

Comment: The tables are not of same schema.I want to create a huge cross joined table from these tables. And I want to join them based on common column between these tables.

Comment: looks like you want something similar to outer join, use DefaultIfEmpty http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/04/07/121103.aspx

Comment: @habib.osu In your example, it is possible because user knows the column of both table. What I am trying to achieve will have different tables every time. In my case, I don't know how I can select new row and apply default value to a column.

Comment: @buffer_overflow: If the merge does not work for you, have a look at this answer which looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260993/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good solution. But what I am looking for is something like outer join. So even if I have values in one table and not in other table, I can still fetch those rows and place some default value say "#ERR" where values for join column are missing in other table.

Answer (score 2):

If both tables have the same primary-key [`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63.aspx) will work:

```
dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2 ,false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

This will merge the schema(columns) of both tables, joins rows which have the same primary-key and add the other rows.

Comment: merge won't give me the output I am looking for. Reason being when I apply a primary key on which base the tables are joined, I get unique rows. But what I need is all rows.