# perform full outer join between two data tables in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have two data tables named as `dtPayments`, `dtRecieptsNew` on which I need to perform full outer join in linq to sql.

I am trying with:

```
var commonColumns = dtPayments.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Intersect( 
        dtRecieptsNew.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>(),
        new DataColumnComparer()
    );

DataTable result = new DataTable();
dtPayments.PrimaryKey = commonColumns.ToArray();

result.Merge(dtPayments, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
result.Merge(dtRecieptsNew, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
```

but i got this error : `The type or namespace name 'DataColumnComparer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assereferrence`

Can u give any Ideas?

Thanking You.
Santosh Srinivas.g

Comment: Was that seriously the error message you got, word for word?

Comment: This is what i got error:The type or namespace name 'DataColumnComparer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assereferrence

Comment: The class `DataColumnCompiler` isn't a BCL class, where does it come from?

Comment: this is DataColumnComparer. Not DataColumnCompiler

Comment: I'm afraid you have to implement that DataColumnComparer class. [follow this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259711/finding-common-columns-from-two-datatable-and-using-those-for-join-condition-in)

Comment: @user2801745 Sorry, my bad, it was a typo in my comment. `DataColumnComparer` doesn't exist in the BCL is what I meant to say.

Comment: @xeondev: ur link is good but it working for common columns(inner joins) can u please tell how  for outer joins ?

Comment: @user2801745 As you probably see now there is no DataColumnComparer class out of the shelf, that was my comment. How to implement one is a different thing, i don't know this moment. Maybe i will investigate later ....